# Integral on the real line between 0 and infinity using contour integration

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

[Question:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZAFt.jpg)

> Let $f(z)=\frac{1}{1+z^{4}}$.
>
> (a) Find the singularity of $f(z)$ in the first quadrant (where $\operatorname{Re} z, \operatorname{Im} z \geq 0$ ).
>
> (b) Calculate the residue of $f(z)$ at the singular point lying in the first quadrant.
>
> (c) Let $\Gamma_{R}$ be the quarter-circle $\Gamma_{R}:|z|=R, \operatorname{Re} z, \operatorname{Im} z \geq 0$, positively oriented. Show that $\lim _{R \rightarrow \infty} \int_{\Gamma_{R}} f(z) d z=0 .$
>
> (d) Determine $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1+x^{4}} d x$.

For part (a) I have that the singularity is at $(1+i)/\sqrt2$ and it is a simple pole?

For part (b) I have that the residue at $f(z)$ at that point is $-(1+i)/4\sqrt2$

For part (c) I used the ML lemma (I am not very good using code so I do not know how to write out my solution without it looking very messy on here.

For part (d) I am a bit stuck, as I have only ever seen examples with the integral between $-\infty$ and $\infty$. Because it is an even function, is the integral between $0$ and $\infty$ just half of the integral between $-\infty$ and $\infty$? What do I do about the integral on the imaginary line?
I am confused... any help would be appreciated.

Comment: A rule of thumb.  If the real integral $\int_a^b f(x)\,dx$ can be computed by contour integration, then the points $a,b$ are typically singularities of the integrand.  In your case, $0$ is not a singularity of $\frac{1}{1+x^4}$, so you have to do something else.  The answers provide the "something else" you could do.

Answer (score 1):

$x^4 = (ix)^4$, so the integral on the half imaginary axis is the same as the integral on the half real line.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, calculate the integral over the whole real line and then divide by $2$ (Pay attention to consider all the residue in the upper half plane)

Another idea would be, as pointed out by Calvin Khor, to use a quarter of a circle and therefore calculating the integral on the positive real line + the one of the positive imaginary axis.

Since these last two integrals are the same, again divide by two to get the correct result

Comment: ah okay, thank you, so is the answer $π/2root2$?

Comment: @bws actually is $\pi/\sqrt 2$ :-)

Comment: @bws ops no I'm sorry, you are correct. Yours is the correct solution :-)